# Pandas Data frame - remove only first dot in dach cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Recently I did some code which produced a csv file. I’m happy with the data itself, but the problem is that separator seems be set as tab and ‘.’. The decimal separator has also been set to ‘.’. I’m trying to acquire data using Jupyter, but I don’t know how to erase only first dot from each cell.
For now my data frame output using read_csv looks like:

```
             .0.000000  .2.000000  .4.000000  .6.000000  ...  .74.000000
.-72.500000  .1.732053  .1.454044  .1.176036  .0.934029  ...   .2.484076   
.-70.500000  .1.768054  .1.740053  .1.752053  .1.858057  ...   .1.554047   
.-68.500000  .1.290039  .1.282039  .1.338041  .1.356041  ...   .1.358041   
.-66.500000  .1.240038  .1.220037  .1.260038  .1.268039  ...   .1.350041   
.-64.500000  .1.224037  .1.232038  .1.220037  .1.244038  ...   .1.330041   
...                ...        ...        ...        ...  ...         ...   
.65.500000   .1.504046  .1.494046  .1.808055  .2.008061  ...   .1.632050   
.67.500000   .0.646020  .0.590018  .0.494015  .0.556017  ...   .2.192067   
.69.500000   .0.214007  .0.186006  .0.200006  .0.264008  ...   .1.186036   
.71.500000   .0.048001  .0.032001  .0.034001  .0.044001  ...  .-0.008000   
.73.500000   .0.032001  .0.024001  .0.012000  .0.006000  ...  .-0.028001
```

Comment: `df.replace('^\\.', '', regex=True)` where `df` is your dataframe

Comment: You could also try to adjust the sep parameter you use when reading the CSV